# How to chat to all

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-hd

I very rarely see chats too all and don't know how to do it myself. Normally it's SHIFT + ENTER
The following hotkeys have been tried:
- SHIFT + ENTER
- CTRL + ENTER
- ALT + ENTER

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also chat to all from the normal chat window (which you open by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>) by adding a `*` in front of your message. (e.g: `*Hi everyone`).

The following prefixes are available:

- `;` Chat to allies (Default in team game)
- `#` Chat to enemies (Default in FFA)
- `*` Chat to everyone

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize the chat by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will pop-up a dialog bar in which you type your message. Note that everybody can read your message, including the enemy :).

Alternatively you can use chat/trumpet icon (second left of the scroll icon) to pop up the chat window in which you can select those who you want to send a message too.
[image: Chat windows location]
 [image: Chat window]